# SaltStack: How to remove a block which was created with file.blockreplace?

Tags: saltstack

I use [file.blockreplace](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.blockreplace) like this:

```
etc_sudoers_{{ system_name }}:
  file.blockreplace:
    - name: /etc/sudoers
    - marker_start: "# START etc_sudoers_{{ system_name }} -DO-NOT-EDIT-"
    - marker_end: "# END etc_sudoers_{{ system_name }} --"
    - content: |
        {{system_name}} ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart apache2*
    - append_if_not_found: True
    - show_changes: True
```

This creates an entry in the file like this:

```
# START etc_sudoers_foo_c123_dpci01051321 -DO-NOT-EDIT-
foo_c123_dpci01051321 ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart apache2*
# END etc_sudoers_foo_c123_dpci01051321 --
```

Now I want to remove the whole block (inclusive the START/END markers). How to do this with saltstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution. Better ones are more than welcome :-)

```
remove_django__etc_sudoers_{{ system_name }}:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/sudoers
    - pattern: "# START etc_sudoers_{{ system_name }} -DO-NOT-EDIT-.*?# END etc_sudoers_{{ system_name }} --"
    - flags: ['MULTILINE', 'DOTALL']
    - repl: ''
    - ignore_if_missing: True
```

Comment: I don't know a better way. I guess blockreplace should have an option to remove the block altogether.

Comment: @ChristopheDrevet-Droguet I created a feature request: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/45370

Comment: The feature request was closed by the timeout bot. I hope I can switch from salt-stack to a different tool soon.